# Determining the working directory of a .so deployed with an Android application

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am deploying a third-party shared object as part of my android application, and this shared object apparently attempts to find a licence file in the "application's working directory".

How do I determine what the working directory is, on a deployed android application, specifically in the context of a shared object?

In my native wrapper, I attempted:

```
    char cwd[PATH_MAX];

    if (getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd)) != NULL) {
        printf("Current working dir: %s\n", cwd);
    } else {
        perror("getcwd() error");
        return 1;
    }
```

cwd ended up as "/"

That don't seem right!

I then attempted to naively write a file:

```
   FILE* fFile = fopen("test.txt","w");
    if (fFile==NULL) {
        printf("Error %d \n", errno);
        printf("It's null");
    }
    fprintf(fFile, "Hello World");
    fclose(fFile);
```

fFile ended up as NULL.    I was under the impression that internal storage has no specific requirements for reads/writes?

The library links just fine on Android, and functions can be exercised - the API merely returns that the license file cannot be found.

Comment: There is no "current working directory" in the classic sense. Do the library's developers support its use on Android?

Comment: Updated Question

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour you witness is correct (in the sense, your app is working as designed). The historical root cause is, probably, that Android apps run in Java Virtual machine, and Java has traditionally not used the "working directory" concept.

But nothing can stop you from setting a working directory to satisfy the expectations of the ported library.